# Delete an object that is a fk in another table Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to delete an object that is reference in another table.

Object I'm trying to delete:

```
 [Table("Local")]
public class Local
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ViejoId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Index("UniqueNuevoId", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [Display(Name ="Nuevo Id")]
    public int NuevoId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Id Unificado")]
    public string UnificadoCon { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Es necesario agregar el nombre del comercio")]
    [Display(Name = "Comercio")]
    public string NombreComercio { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nom Unificado")]
    public string NombreComercioUnificado { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Tel")]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Provincia { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Localidad { get; set; }
    public Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }
    public Estado Estado { get; set; }

    public DateTime FechaIngreso = DateTime.Today;
    public bool Bonificado { get; set; }
    public bool Premium { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Instalación")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime FechaInstalacion { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NotasAdjuntas> notas { get; set; }
```

Object that is associated

```
[Table("NotasAdjuntas")]
public class NotasAdjuntas
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(3)]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Asunto { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Detalle { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime Hora { get; set; }
    public  virtual Local local { get; set; }
    public virtual string username { get; set; }

}
```

I want to delete a "Local", but I understand that if I want to do this, first I have to get rid of the "NotasAdjuntas".

This is my controller (LocalsController)

```
 // GET: Locals/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Local local = db.Locales.Find(id);
        if (local == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(local);
    }

    // POST: Locals/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Local local = db.Locales.Find(id);
        db.Locales.Remove(local);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting any exception when trying to delete a _Local_ entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to mark "local" with required attribute, that should do (EF will generate proper relationship - one-to-many in this case). Means, if you just set up relations properly, it'll do auto-delete of "child" entities for you.

```
[Table("NotasAdjuntas")]
public class NotasAdjuntas
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....
    [Required]  //<<<<< add this
    public virtual Local local { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the notes entries before removing the Local. Something like this:

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    foreach (var nota in local.notas)
    {
        var notaParaEliminar = db.NotasAdjuntas.find(nota.Id);
        db.NotasAdjuntas.Remove(notaParaEliminar);
    }
    Local local = db.Locales.Find(id);
    db.Locales.Remove(local);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```